# Mount a filesystem read-only, and redirect writes to RAM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, readonly

Is it possible to mount a loopback file as read-only, and redirect all writes to RAM?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

#### Update:

It seems there are 2 other simpler ways to do this on Ubuntu (at least the later versions):

1. [`sudo apt-get install overlayroot` followed by setting `overlayroot="tmpfs:swap=1,recurse=0"` in `/etc/overlayroot.local.conf`](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/10/protecting-ubuntu-root-filesystem/).
2. [`sudo apt-get install fsprotect` followed by passing `fsprotect` as a kernel parameter](https://github.com/sharhalakis/fsprotect)

---

#### I finally figured out how to do this with the root filesystem (in Ubuntu 11.04)!

The steps for making a system bootable are simple. I used [this guide](http://www.cianer.com/linux/81-read-only-root-partition-with-aufs) in combination with [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/aufsRootFileSystemOnUsbFlash) and a bunch of web searches to figure out how to get it working properly, without bugs.

Summary:

1. Run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install fsprotect apparmor-utils
   ```
2. Save this to `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/__rootaufs`. I don't think the name actually matters, but the beginning `__` might be used for ordering purposes, so if you change the name, you might want to keep the underscores.
   (This is a copy of [this file](http://www.cianer.com/images/mount_root_aufs).)

   ```
   #!/bin/sh -e

   case $1 in
     prereqs)
       exit 0
       ;;
   esac

   for x in $(cat /proc/cmdline); do
     case $x in
       root=*)
         ROOTNAME=${x#root=}
         ;;
       aufs=*)
         UNION=${x#aufs=}
       case $UNION in
         LABEL=*)
           UNION="/dev/disk/by-label/${UNION#LABEL=}"
           ;;
         UUID=*)
           UNION="/dev/disk/by-uuid/${UNION#UUID=}"
           ;;
       esac    
         ;;
     esac
   done

   if [ -z "$UNION" ]; then
       exit 0
   fi

   # make the mount points on the init root file system
   mkdir /aufs /ro /rw

   # mount read-write file system
   if [ "$UNION" = "tmpfs" ]; then
     mount -t tmpfs rw /rw -o noatime,mode=0755
   else
     mount $UNION /rw -o noatime
   fi

   # move real root out of the way
   mount --move ${rootmnt} /ro

   mount -t aufs aufs /aufs -o noatime,dirs=/rw:/ro=ro

   # test for mount points on union file system
   [ -d /aufs/ro ] || mkdir /aufs/ro
   [ -d /aufs/rw ] || mkdir /aufs/rw

   mount --move /ro /aufs/ro
   mount --move /rw /aufs/rw

   # strip fstab off of root partition
   grep -v $ROOTNAME /aufs/ro/etc/fstab > /aufs/etc/fstab

   mount --move /aufs /root

   exit 0
   ```
3. In `/etc/default/grub`, find the line that starts with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and inside the quotes that follow, add the parameter `aufs=tmpfs`.

   **Bonus:** If you need to occasionally *turn off* the redirection temporarily, simply remove this argument from the kernel parameter list. You can probably do this by holding the Shift key when the system is booting, to show the GRUB menu; then press *e* to edit the parameters, and just erase the `aufs=...` parameter from the list.
4. Append these lines to `/etc/sysctl.conf`. (**Warning**: Potential security risk.)

   ```
   kernel.yama.protected_nonaccess_hardlinks = 0
   kernel.yama.protected_sticky_symlinks = 0
   ```
5. Run these lines:

   ```
   sudo aa-complain dhclient3
   sudo chmod 0755 /etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/__rootaufs
   sudo update-initramfs -k all -u
   sudo update-grub
   ```

If everything went well, when you reboot, you will be doing so into a temporary file system. The RAM part will be at `/rw`, and the disk image will be at `/ro`, but of course it will be read-only.

Nevertheless, if you have booted into a temporary system but need to make a permanent change, you can re-mount the `/ro` file system by saying

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /ro
```

to make it writable, and then you can make whatever modifications needed to that directory.

Answer (score 22):

It is possible using a union filesystem layer like [aufs](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/).

Demo:

#### Create a filesystem image

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/tmp/image bs=1024 count=1024
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1048576 bytes (1.0 MB) copied, 0.0028428 s, 369 MB/s
# mke2fs /tmp/image 
...
```

#### Mount it, populate it

```
# mkdir /tmp/imgmnt
# mount -o loop /tmp/image /tmp/imgmnt
# echo hello > /tmp/imgmnt/hello.txt
# umount /tmp/imgmnt
```

#### Mount it read-only

```
# mount -o loop,ro /tmp/image /tmp/imgmnt
# echo blah > /tmp/imgmnt/hello.txt 
-su: /tmp/imgmnt/hello.txt: Read-only file system
```

#### A small RAM filesystem

```
# mkdir /tmp/rammnt
# mount -t tmpfs -o size=1M none /tmp/rammnt
```

#### Combine both

```
# mkdir /tmp/combined
# mount -t aufs -o br:/tmp/rammnt:/tmp/imgmnt=ro none /tmp/combined
```

That mount option to create a new "branch" (`br`) by stacking `/tmp/rammnt` (read-write) on top of `/tmp/imgmnt` (read-only). This "branch" is made visible as a (read-write) filesystem on `/tmp/combined`.

(See the [aufs(5)](http://aufs.sourceforge.net/aufs3/man.html) man page for all the details.)

Now all that's done, here's what you have:

```
# ls /tmp/combined
hello.txt  lost+found
# cat /tmp/combined/hello.txt 
hello
# echo bye > /tmp/combined/hello.txt 
# cat /tmp/combined/hello.txt 
bye

# cat imgmnt/hello.txt 
hello
# cat rammnt/hello.txt 
bye
```

So the writes "stop" in the `tmpfs` filesystem, they do not attempt to propagate back to the loop-mounted image file.

You could have used a plain directory (on a read/write filesystem), or possibly a directory under `/dev/shm` if that works for you, instead of creating a specific `tmpfs` for that.

---

This technique (or variations thereof) is used by some distribution LiveCD. The Wikipedia [aufs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufs) entry lists a few.

Comment: +1 thanks! A question: (1) is it possible to do this with `fstab`, such that the mount point is `/`? (i.e. so the system boots from a discardable image, pretty much.)

Comment: I don't think so. If you want to do that for `/`, I believe you're better off with an initrd (that's how it is done for livecds I believe). You might be able to do it from an init script though that sounds tricky.

Comment: `fallocate` may be better than `dd` if your filesystem supports it (ext4 does).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by unionfs, see [unionfs.filesystems.org](http://unionfs.filesystems.org). You have mount first read-only filesystem, and as second read-write RAM filesystem through unionfs.

In Ubuntu you can find the unionfs-fuse package, which is another implementation of the same things, but in user space, not as a kernel module.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this on the device level, without a unionfs like aufs. See device-mapper [`snapshot-origin`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/device-mapper/snapshot.txt).